# The proofs in coordinate geometry textbooks are weird.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

So here's my problem: Imagine we want to proof some statement about a line, for example it's equation. What a typical textbook would do is to draw a line, then take a point on a line **in the I quadrant** and then do some constructions and finally prove the statement. Here's where my problem lies: *Why do authors only prove the statement for a point that lies in the I quadrant?* (or only one point in any other quadrant). So what I mean is this: we have a line that passes through any 3 quadrants but textbooks prove the statements **only for one** of those quadrants.

So they prove for a point in one of the quadrants and then say "So for any point on the line we have that...".. But why? I mean a point in the I quadrant has different properties that a point in the II, right? So in the first, x>0 and y>0 but in the second x<0.

So why don't they prove for other quadrants? Is there's some neat trick, an argument for not doing that? Down below there's an image from an old textbooks (I tried modern ones, they are much worse) with a proof of equation for a line. I already "proved" it for most of the possibilities using somekind of shortcut, a method that wasn't presented in the textbook, though I am not sure if it's actually valid or not. Anyways, I'd like to know how would you prove the statement(in case if we really need to prove all of them), I mean none of us would like to prove the statement for all the 12 possibilities, right?(also look another image).

Also, most of the time they took only one line, so for example a line that  passes trough II, I and IV quadrants and prove a statement for that line, and then say "For any line that passes the x axis at a and y-axis at b we have that...". So, in essence they proved the statement for a line that passes through positive x and y axes. Obviously not any line passes through positive parts of the axes.

So in the last image you can see we have 4 possible lines that pass through both axes(not counting the ones that pass through the origin.). And on each of them we have 3 points that lie in different quadrants.

Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The reason why many authors don't treat every case in gory details is often to avoid tedium.

Comment: For true geometry problem, coordinate system is more on the side of a tool to help one getting some numbers out or facts checked. Any coordinate system can be used and it will give you the same answer (in fact MUST). For practical calculation, one pick a coordinate system to make life easiest. It just turns out for most cases, $I$ quadrant alone is enough to get the work/analysis done.

Comment: Okay, thanks you. So, it happened to me that I wanna learn calculus, but I'm either really dumb at understanding statements about functions graphs in algebra or it's the textbooks that don't even try to prove the stuff about graphs. I mean I know how to graph, I understand the very essence of all of it, but I don't undrstnd some more advanced theorems related to graphs of functions.  But I guess it's not me, cause in those algebra textbooks not a single proof of the theorems is present. Basicly I decided to dive deeper into analytical geometry.

Comment: Yes, I probably can just accept those theorems and go on learning calculus, but no, I don't like that :(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

y = y(1) + y(2); where y(1) comes from applying the sine law to $\triangle BPM$ and y(2) = c.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I understood the proof a long time ago, no need to further explain it. My question was a bit different.

Comment: @TimSolnze After reading you post again, I think the logic of the proof is equally applicable to the points and lines located in any other parts of the co-ordinate system,

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is:

The same reasoning and equations work for all cases. The figure is not important when it comes to formal proofs (although this proof is not that formal in my opinion).