# 1st quadrant proofs in coordinate geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

A similar question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649626/the-proofs-in-coordinate-geometry-textbooks-are-weird).

After going through the answers, I wanted to know:

> If I were to prove something in coordinate geometry, (for eg: a general formula,etc) will proving it in the first quadrant give us a general result? Will it apply to all cases?

For eg: Say I've to prove that the area of a triangle is given by:
$$
Area({\triangle})=\frac{1}{2}|(x_{1}y_{2} + x_2y_3 + x_3y_1)-(x_2y_1 + x_3y_2 + x_1y_3)|
$$

If I prove this only in the 1st quadrant, will the result be a general result?

If the answer for the above question is *Yes*, then is there any "proof" to prove that anything we prove in the first quadrant applies to all quadrants, i.e, it is a general result?

Comment: You could also prove that $\text{Area}({\triangle})=\frac{1}{2}\big|(x_{1}y_{2} + \color{red}{|x_2y_3|} + x_3y_1)-(x_2y_1 + x_3y_2 + x_1y_3)\big|$ in the first quadrant, which does not hold true in other quadrants.

Comment: I get your point @dxiv. But in most textbooks, I see all derivations being done in the first quadrant only.

Comment: My point was that you can "*prove*" false statements by considering the first quadrant, only. I would assume your textbooks make some ammends like "*it is enough to consider this quadrant because...*" but, if they don't, you should be looking for more rigorous textbooks.

Comment: @dxiv, can you pls put forward a rigorous argument....about why 1st quadrant is enough?

Comment: The 1st quadrant *is* enough in cases where the statement being proved can be written as a multi-variate polynomial equation or identity, as the posted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4658273/291201) also explains. But you have to know, or otherwise prove, in advance that it is indeed a polynomial.

Comment: @dxiv, but the area formula mentioned in the question doesn't seem like a polynomial.

Comment: It is a [multi-variate polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Multivariate_polynomial) in $x_i,y_j$. In fact, it's even a [multilinear polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_polynomial) though that's not relevant in this context.

Comment: @dxiv, thanks for the clarification!! I thought it wasn't a polynomial for it used the absolute value function

Comment: I didn't even notice that, to be honest. The formula is usually given without the absolute value around the whole expression, for the *signed* area of a triangle (which can be positive or negative depending on orientation). Technically, the absolute value is not a polynomial function, but this particular formula still is, because you can get rid of the absolute value by writing it squared as $Area^2 = \frac{1}{4}\big(\ldots\big)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the square of area$(\Delta)$ is a polynomial in the coordinates $x_i$, $y_i$. It can be seen as a function of the three points, so as a function defined on ${\bf R}^2\times {\bf R}^2\times{\bf R}^2$.

If you have two polynomials that are equal in the first quadrant, they are equal everywhere. This comes from the fact that the set of points where a non-constant polynomial vanishes is of lower dimension than the space on which it is defined. Hence it cannot contain an non-empty open set without being equal to the whole set.

In your example, it is known a priori that the square of the area is a polynomial because it is given by a determinant (a Gram determinant to be precise). So showing the formula mentioned in your question for a triple of vectors all belonging to the quarter plan is enough to ensure that it is valid everywhere.

There are many quantities in plane geometry that are related to polynomials, but not all. As shown in the comments, one must be cautious when dealing with the absolute values, signs, inequalities and orientation. For example, the non-oriented angle between a vector in the quarter plane and the x-axis is between $0$ and $\pi \over 2$ but this does not extend to all vectors of the plane. Here the angle is given by
$\Bigl| \arccos\Bigl({x \over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Bigr) \Bigr|$. This is definitely not a polynomial.